# tightVnc Viewer: no connection could be made

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvnc

I have a VPS running ubuntu 14.10, I correctly installed VNC which ran fine for one day. However yesterday when I tried to connect to my VNC using tightvnc viewer it said no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. I tried different ports, and I found an old post on stackoverflow but it didn't help.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that SO post for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your VNC session is still alive? Try telnet to the VNC server's port (typically 5900 + VNC port num). If you get connection refused or timed out, your session must not exist anymore.

Comment: i reinstalled xrd and now it works